# Integrate PayPal(MECL) library in Android app

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate paypal_mecl library in android app. i have download example code and paypal_mecl library from [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index). I just go through demo app but i am not able to understood how can i add my purchase information like different items and money for that items..
In demo app they have load url in webview (http://paydemo.sms4me.com/ECDemo-server/cart.jsp?)
what does that cart.jsp page contains??
or is there any other way to handle payment process by paypal_mecl??

Thanks...

Comment: cant access the link https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MECL (as opposed to MPL) it is necessary to have your own website. In the PayPal example the cart.jsp receives the cart information (eg size=Large&toppings=Peperoni, etc) and the device token as part of the URL, and displays a Mobile Shopping Cart Page with a Checkout with PayPal button. It'll later call a SetExpressCheckout with the payment information.

To find what's involved the paypal_nvp_java_sdk will be the best resource as it has a set of JSP samples.

You can push more of the work onto the Android client, but you'd still need to have your own website handling the forwarding of three requests and responses between the phone and PayPal. The primary reason of going via a secure server is to keep your API credentials from prying eyes.